# How can I read 2 consecutive lines of a text file and save them as temporary variables

Tags: batch-file, text-processing

I have files with an `ID`, `model`, and `date`. the files have a format similar to `10000_9999-99_10-01-2011.zip` (where `10000` is the `ID`, `9999-99` is the `model`, and of course `10-01-2011` is the `date`).

I would like to modify the `date`s of these files, but maintain the interval between sessions with the same `ID`. For example, if 2 sessions had the dates `1/1/2011` and `2/1/2011`, and I wanted to update the last session date to `8/1/2012`, the first session would have the date `7/1/2012`.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
del filedates.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=_" %%a in (filenames.txt) do @echo %%c >>filedates.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%a in (filedates.txt) do (
  echo %%a%%b
)
```

---

The output is similar to this (YearMonth):

```
201107
201109
201204
etc..
```

---

I was looking to read a line in `filedates.txt`, store this date as a variable, then read the next line, and store this as another variable. That way the two variables could be compared to see which is greater, and the process would continue.

Comment: MS-DOS did not support the extended for loop using the `/F` parameter so you must be using Windows (NT or later).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, since you're obviously running a fairly recent version of Windows (based on the `setlocal` and `for /f` syntax), is there a reason you're not doing this in `PowerShell`, which would make it much easier?

Comment: I working on a code which is nearly complete. All of this code is written using the command line, otherwise I would use powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward way to do read two lines at a time is to process the lines in the input file one by one with a `for /f` loop, and "react" only on even numbered lines. Here's a sample code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set evenflag=1
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (filedates.txt) do set x1=!x2! && set x2=%%x && (
set /a evenflag^^=1 && if !evenflag!==1 (
    rem Do something with !x1! and !x2!
))
```

Here the variable `evenflag` is a boolean flag that indicates whether the current line number is even (`1` for even lines, `0` to odd lines). `x1` and `x2` hold the currently read pair of lines.